# If you had a fusion reactor the size of a suitcase, would it be possible to power a car with it via a steam turbine with 1950's level technology?

Tags: science-fiction, alternate-history, science-in-society, thermodynamics

The specifics of the reactor are intentionally vague. It would be a form of lattice-confinement, produce very little radiation, and be scaled up or down very easily. I'm working on a Fallout-like universe set in an alternate 1950's. Aside from the fusion technology, the level of technology is unchanged from OTL. I know battery technology was very primitive at the time, so I thought that having a pure EV would never have the range or durability to compete with gasoline cars of the time. So does having a steam turbine drive the wheels directly make sense? Is it feasible for the engineering of that era? Would it be too impractical?

Comment: With a fusion reactor on board you do not need any battery for an EV to be run. Well it wouldn't be called a "pure EV" but FV "Fusion Vehicle" but still use mostly the same technology besides replacing the battery with the Fursion reactor

Comment: [Steam-powered automobiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_car) were once upon a time a serious competitor to internal combustion engine automobiles. Yes, you can make a steam engine small enough to fit in a passenger car. This has been possible since the 1890s. No turbine necessary.

Comment: do you mean fission? you can still correct it you know. Yes it is possible to have a suitcase the size of a 10 storeys building in the 1950s.

Comment: 1. @datacube I should have specified that this would be a deuterium-fueled reactor. I believe that would only produce heat energy, I think.

Comment: @user6760 No, fusion energy. It's a macguffin, not really grounded by our known physics. It just works. Now the technology harnessing it's energy, that's all grounded by our rules.

Answer (score 3):

## Go hybrid

You write "I thought that having a pure EV would never have the range or durability to compete with gasoline cars of the time", and this is true.

But then you write "So does having a steam turbine drive the wheels directly make sense?"

What happened here is that you skipped a step, one that was well known in the 1950s: hybrid drive. Diesel-electric trains debuted in large scale in the 1930s, and looked pretty awesome for the time.

[image]

*The [EMC EA/EB locomotive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMC_EA/EB) came into service in 1937 ([image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMC_EA/EB#/media/File:Capitol_Limited_EMD_EA_and_Tom_Thumb_1937.jpg))*

Yes, battery technology at the time was abject [crap], however, with a suitcase sized heat source, you have *plenty* of space over in the motor compartment to fill with a steam turbine, a generator, and a beefy battery pack.

Your biggest problem will actually be...

...cooling.

The steam tubine operate with the Rankine cycle. And at the very best, you can get about 40% of the heat that was generated, as locomotion / electricity. The other 60% needs to be dumped overboard. And that is not easy with something as small as a car!

Otto/diesel cycle cars solve it by dumping a lot of the heat with the exhaust, and the rest via the radiator, and radiative cooling of the engine block and exhaust system. You do not have that in your vehicle. So there will need to be built an extensive cooling system, probably taking up most of the underside of your fusion-driven car, with radiators dumping heat into the air.

In any case, a hybrid solution for your fusion-powered car is feasible, yes. But it is a challenge to get that solution to work, it is not one that comes neatly and tightly packaged, even if the core of the drive is.

## "Why not go direct drive?"

Because, look at steam locomotvies. That is how complicated it needs to be to do direct drive. Hybrid, by doing away with gearboxes, transmissions and similar, is a more compact solution, and allows the turbine to run at peak efficiency for much more of the time, without having to add provisions for it running outside its comfort zone.

Comment: Thank you for the very intensive answer! I had considered a steam-turbine-to-battery thing at first, but I assumed that would be too complicated for the times. I didn't even think about trains. I thought cooling would add weight, but I didn't consider the sheer complexity of it. We may need more sci-fi magic lol. Thank you again.

Comment: @BigDumb, "German engineer Andreas Flocken built the first real electric car in 1888. Electric trains were also used to transport coal out of mines, as their motors did not use up precious oxygen. Before the pre-eminence of internal combustion engines, electric automobiles also held many speed and distance records." ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_electric_vehicle))

Comment: Just wanted to point out that diesel-electric are still in common use (they are the most common type of diesel locomotives).